# Clicking sub-level link in menu does not work

Tags: css, menu

Having trouble with this site I am trying to maintain here: http://www.homehatchery.com/

I can't seem to get the sub-level links to work in the main nav. When hovering over them I can see that it is a link, but it won't work when clicking on it. I thought it might be a z-index issue, but I don't believe it is.

Any ideas?

Comment: to start with you have a javascript error that fires each time I try to click your navigation links. It looks like to me you have custom js handling your link clicks and with the error it isn't finishing.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined custom.js:210

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your javascript error is because this function gets the part of the url after the '#', but on your homepage your url does not fit that specification:

```
$(".scroll").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var full_url = this.href;
    var parts = full_url.split("#");
    var trgt = parts[1];
    var target_offset = $("#" + trgt).offset();
    var target_top = target_offset.top;

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target_top
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: The fix would be to adjust your code to get a value on the homepage.

Comment: If that is true, commenting it our might be appropriate, thoguh not advised as a permanent solution for a live site. However returning true at the beginning of a function to stop it from working is a terrible idea! It is non-indicative of the status of the code execution...that's what a comment would be for...

Comment: can't believe I missed that! On vacation and trying to fix this asap. Thanks! This was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your smooth scrolling is interfering with it.
what you would have to do is remove the class "scroll" form the menu items and that should fix it.

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it...